# Scanner -NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I am  executing the below code to read a string from the  input stream with the scanner object.

```
   public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userInput1 = getUserInput();
        System.out.println(userInput1);
        String userInput2 = getUserInput();
        System.out.println(userInput2);     
    }

private static String getUserInput() {
        System.out.println("Enter the String");
        Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.next();
        scanner.close();
        return input;
    }
}
```

The first invocation to the method getUserInput succeeded without any issues.But he second invocaton threw NoSuchElementException.

```
Enter the String
test1
test1
Enter the String
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the code

1. It assumes that there already has been input. A simple `while(!scanner.hasNext()){}` before the locations where you call `scanner.next();` should work.
2. You are creating many scanners (this may or may not impact the code, but does impact efficiency)
   Instead, the `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` can be broken up into a declaration (`Scanner scanner;`) outside a method and then defined (`scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`) in the main method or initialization code.

Comment: Calling `hasNext` and `next` on `System.in` has the same effect: these calls block the thread until there is a token to read. So there is no point in using that `while` loop.

Comment: @Tom But you can use it for input type checking ("please enter a number" when someone types a string)

Comment: So, somthing like `System.out.print("enter number: "); while(!scanner.hasNextInt()){}`? This is a bad idea for type checking. You might want to try it, to find out why.

Comment: No: more like `System.out.print("enter number: "); while(!scanner.hasNextInt()){ System.out.println(/*Some message*/); scanner.next(); } result = scanner.nextInt();`